# ID generation method stuck in a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I am using the following method to generate an ID number. It starts with the number 0, and compares it to the ID numbers of all existing objects in an array, if it does not equal any of the objects then it should return that ID number and break out of the loop. If it does equal any of the objects it will + 1 and compare 1 to the ID numbers of all objects, until it finds a number that does not match/ is not in use.

However when I run the program, the for loop loops indefinitely, despite being controlled by a boolean which is triggered when all object IDs have been compared and non match. Here is the code:

```
 public int GenerateProductID(){

Boolean NewIDFound = false;
Boolean inUse = false;
int potentialID;


for(potentialID=0;NewIDFound==false;potentialID++){

    for(Product productToCompare: this.Products){

        if (potentialID==productToCompare.getID()){
            {inUse=true;}
        }
    }
    if(inUse!=true){
        NewIDFound=true;
        return potentialID;


    }
}
return potentialID;//Had to return something here although the function will never get here. 
}
```

I have spent a while trying to get to the bottom of this, Java is a new endeavour so apologies in advance if something obvious has been missed. Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `break` to exit the for loop, instead of using a variable you mutate in the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inUse` means "the current potentialID is in use"; as such, it needs to be reset for each new potentialID.